# What kind of ranking Facebook provides when using their search API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook provides search using queries with  different object types, any idea what is the ranking that Facebook imposes on the results, or is there a way to influence that ranking (i.e. by number of likes or shares etc)

Also I didn't find a way to specify the object type 'photo' by looking at the API provided below, is there a way to specify the 'photo' as a object type to search?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/

Answer (score 0):

One can reasonably assume that Facebook's relevance algorithm is not a simple across-the-board solution. Rather, its likely different for each person. If a lot of my friends like a page, I'd be more likely to see it in results than you are. That's where the `access_token` comes into play.

To answer your 2nd question: `Post` objects have a `type` parameter. Obviosuly if you POST to Photo endpoint, etc, it'll obvious that its a photo. I'm not 100% sure, but one can reasonably assume that qhen you POST to `/me/feed` endpoint, facebook will figure out what "main" action surround. If there's a link involved, its probably a link. If its a checkin with a photo, its probably all a checkin. Etc.

Comment: Access token is not a required field for most of the search queries.

How do i specify that in the query I need posts only with photos, any example?

Comment: Right, but `access_token` probably changes it. Anyways, there is no "search only posts with photos" via the search API. You'll have to loop through the results and see if the post's data contains a photo